# Quite a distance from the start to the end of this short riddle. Who am I?

Tags: riddle

> Eight furlongs fall between my twin ends.
>   Remembering fond days or greeting good friends,
>   All those who see me suspect that they please.
>   To summon me, several folks need to say cheese.

I've enjoyed reading riddles on this site, and thought I'd try writing one. Who is the speaker of this poem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think it's

> smiles

Eight furlongs fall between my twin ends.

> 8 furlongs = 1 mile, and "mile" is in the middle of Smiles! The twin ends are the s's.

Remembering fond days or greeting good friends,

> Reasons to smile

All those who see me suspect that they please.

> If someone sees you smile, they think that they are making you happy (pleasing you)

To summon me, several folks need to say cheese.

> Saying cheese makes people smile

Comment: Almost there! But the first clue is literal, and the last clue mentions several folks.

Comment: Yay! You got all the parts, in addition to getting the answer right. I wasn't trying to be finicky about your first answer, but close as it was, it didn't meet all the clues

Comment: Yeah I wasnt so sure about it either, but after your hint, then it finally clicked with me. Nice riddle.

Answer (score 4):

> I think it's a picture being taken?

Eight furlongs fall between my twin ends.

> I don't know this one...

Remembering fond days or greeting good friends

> A photo let's you remember fond days and good friends.

All those who see me suspect that they please.

> People who take the photo want the people in the photo to smile.

To summon me, several folks need to say cheese.

> They ask the people in the photo to say cheese.