# A Riddle for Puzzlers

Tags: riddle, wordplay

> My first is found in Aquaman's new super-secret lair.
>   My second is a prison where a climbing snail's ensnared.
>   My third, repeated seven times, requires punctuation.
>   My fourth comprises eight furlongs; embodies termination.
>   My fifth must be connected to three homes with expertise.
>   My whole, a famous work of art, comprises all of these.

What am I talking about?

Comment: Just saw this way late, but this is one of my favorite puzzles.  NJ!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The answer is

> All's Well That Ends Well, a famous Shakespeare play.

My first is found in Aquaman's new super-secret lair.

> This is an amusing reference to [Aquaman's Revenge!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/18153/aquamans-revenge), in which one of your possessions is an **awl**.

My second is a prison where a climbing snail's ensnared.

> This is a reference to https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/248/how-long-does-it-take-for-the-snail-to-get-out-of-the-well. In the problem, the snail is trapped in a **well**.

My third, repeated seven times, requires punctuation.

> This is a reference to [A grammatically valid sentence in English containing seven "that"'s in a row?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/2578/a-grammatically-valid-sentence-in-english-containing-seven-thats-in-a-row). The word in question is **that**.

My fourth comprises eight furlongs; embodies termination.

> This refers to [Quite a distance from the start to the end of this short riddle. Who am I?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/11888/quite-a-distance-from-the-start-to-the-end-of-this-short-riddle-who-am-i).  The word in question is **ends**.  It certainly does embody termination, as termination is the end of something.

My fifth must be connected to three homes with expertise.

> This is a cute reference to [Connect 3 houses with 3 wells](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/17230/connect-3-houses-with-3-wells), in which three houses must be connected to three **wells** without the pipes crossing.

Comment: Each line was actually a reference to a puzzle on this site.  The ones that you missed:
http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/248/how-long-does-it-take-for-the-snail-to-get-out-of-the-well |
http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/2578/a-grammatically-valid-sentence-in-english-containing-seven-thats-in-a-row |
http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/11888/quite-a-distance-from-the-start-to-the-end-of-this-short-riddle-who-am-i

Comment: Thanks! I actually knew the snail one existed, but I didn't link to it since I was already familiar with the riddle. Didn't know about the other two puzzles, though! That makes the 'ends' line make much more sense.

Comment: I added references to the puzzles in question to your answer.  If you don't like what I've done, feel free to revert.

Comment: Brilliant! I love how it draws on the other puzzles